# Android notification large icon on the left

Tags: android, notifications

There are multiple questions I have about android notification template. From what I know in previous android versions large icons were located on the left side, starting from android 7 they were moved to the right. And on all my devices(android 8-10) the large icon was indeed on the right side. But in this documantation, in section "Wear OS devices" there is a notification that has it's large icon on the left side and there is a small icon attached to bottom right corner.Also on the same image, the last notification, it seems like it has two large icons on the left and right, is that correct? Recently I've seen some apps on android 10 that have their notification icons moved to the left, and on android 11 with both left and right large image(look at the screenshots). So my questions are:

1. How to create notification with both left and right large icons?
2. How to create notification with left large icon?

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#compatibility

[image: Android 11 notification with both large images]

[image: Android 10 notification with large image on the left side]

Comment: this question is still very relevant, @Danil did you find a solution for this yet?

Answer (score 2):

[image]This is Conversation Notifications which uses MessagingStyle, read more here

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/conversations

To answer you question this is how you would

```
  @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun showNotification(
    message: RemoteMessage,
    profileImageBitmap: Bitmap?,
    primaryAttachmentBitmap: Bitmap?
) {
    val title = message.data["title"] // extract title from your notification payload
    val description = message.data["description"] // extract description from your notification payload
    val action = message.data["action"]
    val groupID = message.data["groupId"] //  // extract group id from your notification payload. Only used if you want to group your notificaiton which ive done here to. 

    val intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        applicationContext,
        0,
        getIntentForAction(deeplink, action, title, message.messageId),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )

    val person: Person =
        Person.Builder()
            .setIcon(profileImageBitmap?.let { IconCompat.createWithAdaptiveBitmap(it) })
            .setName(title)
            .setKey(Math.random().toString())
            .build()


    val shortcut =
        ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(this, ZAP_SHORTCUT_ID)
            .setLongLived(true)
            .setPerson(person)
            .setShortLabel(title.toString())
            .setIntent(
                (Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("https://www.turnip.com/")
                ))
            )
            .setIcon(profileImageBitmap?.let { IconCompat.createWithAdaptiveBitmap(it) })
            .build()
    ShortcutManagerCompat.pushDynamicShortcut(this, shortcut)

    val messageArrivalTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

    var textMessage: NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message? = null
    textMessage = NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message(
        description,
        messageArrivalTime,
        person
    )

    var imageMessage:
            NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message? = null

    primaryAttachmentBitmap?.let {
        val file = saveDownloadedImageToTempFile(this, primaryAttachmentBitmap)
        val fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "gg.turnip.android.fileprovider", file)


        imageMessage =
            NotificationCompat.MessagingStyle.Message(
                description,
                messageArrivalTime,
                person
            ).also {
                it.setData("image/", fileUri)
            }
    }


    val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder =
        NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_turnip_small) // notification icon
            .setLargeIcon(profileImageBitmap)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setShortcutId(ZAP_SHORTCUT_ID)
            .setGroup(groupID)
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(intent)
            .setContentTitle("display name")

    val summaryNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setLargeIcon(profileImageBitmap)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_turnip_small)
        .setStyle(
            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()

        )
        .setGroup(groupID)
        .setGroupSummary(true)
        .build()



    val chatMessageStyle: MessagingStyle = MessagingStyle(person)
    chatMessageStyle
        .addMessage(textMessage)
        .addMessage(imageMessage)
        .setBuilder(notificationBuilder)


    val notificationManager =
        getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channelId = CHANNEL_ID
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            channelId, "Watch Party Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        notificationBuilder.setChannelId(channelId)
    }

    NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).apply {
        notify(System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), notificationBuilder.build())
        notify(groupID.hashCode(), summaryNotification)
    }

    textMessage = null
    imageMessage = null

}
```

// setIcon() : method above  takes an IconComapt, you can download any image from your s3 server using glide save it as bitmap and use that bitmap to show user profile image on the left side.

// primaryAttachmentBitmap is a bitmap dowloaded from my s3 server using glide, and its  only requried if you need to show an image on the right side of your notification next to your message. like how its used in the imageMessage above.

// summaryNotification is used when you want to group your messages, if you dont need grouping you can skip it.

Answer (score 0):

I think to show both the right and left icon (one of them are significant), you can add the large icon inside the `setStyle(...)` builder method to set the large and small icons. Please give the following snippet a shot to resolve your issue. Thank you

```
// Create the left and right large icons
Bitmap leftIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.<left_large_icon>);
Bitmap rightIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.<right_large_icon>);

// Create the notification
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
        .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
        .setContentText("Notification Text")
        .setLargeIcon(leftIcon)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                .bigPicture(rightIcon)
                .bigLargeIcon(null)) // or if you need any
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Comment: thnx for responding but this is simply a big picture style notificaiton, what the image in the question shows is that the left side icon (to the left of letter "G" ) needs to be a user defined image ( example : download user profile pic from server) and NOT the app icon.

Comment: Basically this is a new conversation style message used alongside Messaging style notification. Ive got the answer for this will be posting it in a couple of days

Comment: Nice, would like to see your update soon.